# How to select non empty CSV cells and put them into an array in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

Is there a way to select non empty/null elements into an array? For example:

Current csv: (The "___" represents empty such as '')

```
Col1     Col2
1       "hello"
2       "adsf"
3       "hi"
__
__
```

Result I want:

```
$array = (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have enough memory to read the CSV file into memory in full, you can combine [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) with the array-filtering abilities of PowerShell's comparison operators (`-ne` in this case):

```sh
# Simulate reading a CSV file into an array of $objects.
# (instead of: $objects = Import-Csv ...)
$objects = 
@'
Col1,Col2
1,"hello"
2,"adsf"
3,"hi"
,"..."
,"..."
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# .Col1 returns the "Col1" column values as an array,
# and -ne '' filters out the empty-string values.
$array = @($objects.Col1) -ne ''
```

Note:

- `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is used to ensure that `$objects.Col1` returns an *array* of values, even if the CSV file happens to have just *one* data row.
- With an array as the LHS, `-ne` acts as a *filter* (rather than returning `$true` or `$false`) and returns the *subarray* of matching elements (those who aren't the empty string). Note that the result too is then an array, even with a single-element LHS.

---

Otherwise, if the CSV file is too large to read into memory in full, you need to use a *pipeline* (this will be slower):

```sh
[array] $array =
@'
Col1,Col2
1,"hello"
2,"adsf"
3,"hi"
,"..."
,"..."
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object { if ('' -ne $_.Col1) { $_.Col1 } }
```

Note:

- Type constraint `[array]` ensures that the output collected from the pipeline is always treated as an array, even if only *one* value happens to be returned (the alternative would be to wrap the entire pipeline in `@(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Col1 is a string

```
Import-Csv C:\path\to\test.csv | ?{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Col1)}
```

Comment: Note that `Import-Csv` only ever creates `[string]` properties. Your solution returns whole rows (objects) not just the `.Col1` values.